# Condition Weird Behavior

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

We get the **validity** `parameter` as **False** and we use **if condition** as follow:

```
if not validity:
    // logic
```

Why `python3` is satisfying this condition? not sure about `python2`.

Does anyone know about this weird behavior?

Try1:

```
validity = False
if not validity is True:
   print("11111111111111111111111")
else:
   print("22222222222222")
```

Comment: If clause is satisfied when it is `True`. When your `validity` is `False`, `not validity` is `True`. Thus the if clause is satisfied.

Comment: hello @hata it is still now worked. I've edited in question it will break the clause.

Comment: Which output do you expect, `11111...` or `22222...`? I think the former is not weird.

Comment: I'm expecting that if you check in this way if not validity then it must be print - "22222". isn't it?

Comment: (1) `validity is True` means `False is True`, so the result is `False`. (2) `not False` means `True`. If clause is satisfied and the result is `11111...`.

Comment: But why it will not check with not and value in the clause? just simply getting bool and I'm taking with the simple condition then why I have to addon check with if it is True or == True?